# "Curl error (5): Couldn't resolve proxy name" error

Tags: curl, proxy, environment-variables, fedora-23

I am trying to install php on my system using command 'sudo yum install php-common'. But it is giving following error

```
Error: Error downloading packages:
Curl error (5): Couldn't resolve proxy name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f23&arch=x86_64
[Could not resolve proxy: proxy.iiit.ac.in]
```

I have unset my proxy environment variables and tried again but it is still not working. Whenever I am using 'yum update' or 'yum install' to update or install some packages, it is giving same error.

How can I remove proxy? Please help.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You need help diagnosing a problem with `yum`, which has been configured to use an HTTP proxy whose hostname cannot currently be resolved. If `yum` usually works, it may be a temporary issue.

Comment: 'yum' is working when I used it from my college's network. Outside of my college's network, it is not working. because I have set proxy setting to use my college's network.

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue with the proxy.
In Miktex go to the "Packages" side. It says "Install from ..." and next to it there is the button "Change". Go here and add your credentials, i.e. Username:Password@proxy and choose any port, e.g. 8080.